# DotVVM Authentication get null exception

Tags: c#, dotvvm

When is called method SignIn I get error NullReferenceExepction.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public Masterpage1ViewModel() {
        UserIdentity user = new UserIdentity("Admin");
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(user);

        Context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(claimsIdentity);
  }
```

Here is class for UserIdentity:

```
public class UserIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public string AuthenticationType
    {
        get { return DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie; }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public UserIdentity(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Also I added to Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = e => DotvvmAuthenticationHelper.ApplyRedirectResponse(e.OwinContext, e.RedirectUri)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ClaimsIdentity` is not initialized correctly, maybe the combination with `UserIdentity` crashes somewhere inside OWIN Cookie Security Middleware.

We use the following code to initialize it:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName),
    // add another claims (e.g. for each role)
},
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
Context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
```